# how to change Lens offset or alignment in jqzoom

Tags: jquery, jqzoom

I am using jQuery plugin 'jqzoom'. I am facing issue while positioning the Lens on the image. my image is center aligned but lens is aligned to the div border which contains the image. In simple words i want to set the lens position to be started from the image border not the div border.

Comment: You need to post your code too

Comment: application is using "jquery.jqzoom-core.js" file and i have hardly made some class name change. I found the source code flow A bit difficult to understand other wise i could have resolved this by making changes to the source code.